# Top function in sql for each alphabet

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

If i have a table with a column values alpha, azera, beta, brown, charlie, cling

How do i get the values like azera, brown and cling since "al" in alpha comes first "az" in azera.. I started using this in SQL 2005.

```
Select top 1 columnA from TableA order by ColumnA desc
```

It gives me only 1 result but i need to get for each alphabet A B and C.

Thank you in advance

Comment: unclear. try adding more detail or table.

Comment: I want the largest value for each starting letter when alphabetically sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little unclear but I'm assuming you want the largest (when alphabetically sorted) value for each starting letter. That is, if it were a dictionary you want the last entry for `a`, the last entry for `b`, and so on. If so, try:

```
SELECT MAX(myCol)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY LEFT(myCol,1)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aec4c/4)

Comment: +1 clever. I also thought same way as other two answers but this is different and easy.

Comment: Thank you! I was not very clear but you gave me the right answer. You have explained it clearly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I am going to speculate that by "alphabet" you mean "first letter".  You can solve this using `row_number()`:

```
select columnA
from (select columnA,
             row_number() over (partition by left(columnA, 1) order by columnA desc) as seqnum
      from TableA
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by columnA
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to partition by the first letter and get one word for every letter.

You could use a `CTE` with `Row_Number` function:

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT ColumnA, 
                rn=Row_number() 
                     OVER( 
                       partition BY Substring(ColumnA, 1, 1) 
                       ORDER BY ColumnA DESC) 
         FROM   TableA) 
SELECT * 
FROM   cte 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

[**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a7459/5/0)

Result:

```
azera   
brown   
cling
```